# I am unable to install django from command prompt. I am attaching the error. please show the path to me

Tags: python, django, cmd

C:\Users\utkarsh>pip install django
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\utkarsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install django': The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

in your cmd type "python -m pip install django"